# C++ inheritance of template objects (G++ compiler)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CFirstLevel {
 public:
    CFirstLevel (const string & _name): name (_name) {}
    // ...

 protected:

    string name;

};

template <typename T>
class CSecondLevel: public CFirstLevel {
 public:

    CSecondLevel (const string & _name): CFirstLevel (_name) {}

    virtual void PushBack (T) = 0;
    virtual void Print    (int I) {cout << data [I] << endl;}
    // ...

 protected:
    vector<T> data; 
};

template <typename A>
class CThirdLevel: public CSecondLevel<A> {
 public:
    CThirdLevel (const string & _name): CSecondLevel<A> (_name) {}

    virtual void PushBack (A _value) {data.push_back (_value);}

};


int main ( void ) {

    CThirdLevel<int> * pointer = new CThirdLevel<int> ("third");
    pointer -> PushBack (111);

    pointer -> Print (0);

    return 0;

}
```

Compiler return error:

main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void CThirdLevel::PushBack(T)’:

main.cpp:32:37: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope

Where is a problem? Is it possible use this inheritance?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing protected members of superclass in C++ with templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010281/accessing-protected-members-of-superclass-in-c-with-templates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in `CThirdLevel`. The field `data` cannot be resolved from `CSecondLevel`. You can solve this by changing

```
virtual void PushBack (A _value) {data.push_back (_value);}
```

to

```
virtual void PushBack (A _value) {CSecondLevel<A>::data.push_back (_value);}
```

Comment: Or `this->data.push_back(_value);`

Comment: The reason for this is is C++'s 'two-phase name lookup', where names in templates are either dependent or non-dependent (on the template parameters). You need `data` to be classified as dependent, but without `this->` or `CSecondLevel<A>::` it gets classified as non-dependent. Note that not all compilers do two-phase lookup properly; VC++ in particular is known for being lax.

Answer (score 2):

As Marc suggested, use

```
virtual void PushBack (A _value) { CSecondLevel<A>::data.push_back (_value); }
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
virtual void PushBack (A _value) { this->data.push_back (_value); }
```