# C++ derived template class: Access protected member of an instance

Tags: c++, templates, friend, derived

I have a template base class, and a derived template class.  The derived one has a an overloaded method with an argument that holds a reference to an object of the same type of the base class.  If these weren't a template class, I would have made the derived class a friend of the base class so that I can access the base's protected members in this case, but how do I do this with templates?

```
template <typename T>
class base
{
    // If this wasn't a template class, I would have done this:
    // friend class derived;

public:
    base(T val)
        : val_(val)
    {
    }

    virtual void assign(const base<T>& other)
    {
        val_ = other.val_;
    }

protected:
    T val_;
};

template <typename T>
class derived : public base<T>
{
public:
    derived(T val)
        : base<T>(val)
    {
    }

    virtual void assign(const base<T>& other)
    {
        this->val_ = other.val_; // error: ‘int base<int>::val_’ is protected
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived<int> a(5);
    derived<int> b(6);
    b.assign(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `base<T>::assign(other);`? Why is `derived` responsible for managing the state of `base`? Anyway, if you really want to use `friend`, you can: `template <typename T> class derived; template <typename T> class base { friend class derived<T>; };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010281/accessing-protected-members-of-superclass-in-c-with-templates

Comment: cmbasnett: It's not, actually I have read that particular question before I posted and tried what was suggested in there, but this case is different.  I'm trying to access a protected member of another instance.

Comment: Igor, thanks the forward declaration of the template class and declaring it as a friend seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why having `virtual`? In your example `derived::assign()` does the same as `base::assign()`.

```
class base
{
    ...
    public:
    ...
    void assign(const base<T>& other)
    ...
}
```

> ```
> derived<int> b(6);
> b.assign(a); //calls base<int>::assign(..)
> ```

If `derived` should do some more work in `assign(..)`, use
`base<T>::assign(other);` [as proposed by Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771109/c-derived-template-class-access-protected-member-of-an-instance/33957164#comment27673451_18771109). No need to use `friend`.